# ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, importerror

I was trying to use the Pyfladesk and I ended up with an import error:

```
ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have been trying to fix it but have not had any successful attempts as of now. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if this will help or not but here is full Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samrat/Documents/Facial-Recognition-Attendance-Tracker/Interface.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyfladesk import init_gui

  File "/home/samrat/Documents/Facial-Recognition-Attendance-Tracker/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyfladesk/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets

ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your distro? How did you install pyfladesk?

Comment: @eyllanesc I pip install pyfladesk. I am currently on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: try with: `python3 -m pip install pyqt5  pyfladesk` and execute your script with: `python3 your_script.py`

Comment: @eyllanesc I am still getting the same error

Comment: show the complete error message

Comment: @eyllanesc added it to my post above^

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's effectively a question about distro-specific software installation, not software development.

Comment: ...which is to say, you need to install whichever package contains `libQt5QmlModels.so.5` (or its missing dependency, whatever that is). That's a native library, so you install it with `apt` or `dpkg`, not `pip`. Still, this isn't a problem with your code, so it doesn't belong here on Stack Overflow; it's strictly a problem with your operating system's Qt installation.

Comment: If you have a copy of `libQt5QmlModels.so.5` on your system (probably somewhere under `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64`, or such), btw, you can use `ldd` to list its dependencies and see which ones aren't installed. If you *don't* have a copy of that library, well, that's your problem right there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I doubt that it is off-topic since it is a problem related to programming: Problems with the installation of a library in a certain OS, obviously this question would also be valid in other stackexchange sites such as askubuntu since it is a problem that overlaps both sites. In general, pypi provides all binaries except for exceptional cases where it has to be compiled with local dependencies, but this is not the case for PyQt5.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Stack Overflow only permits questions about problems **unique** to software development (that's ANDed, not ORed, into other conditions in [What questions can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center). Someone running a Qt app, not writing one at all, would have the same problem; thus, it's not unique to software development.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Libraries like pyfladesk are *software tools commonly used by programmers*. A simple example to understand is with VLC and libvlc, the first is a player that if a user has a problem with the configuration and another question is how to integrate libvlc with Qt, the first is not valid for SO but the second is valid. Based on the name of the OP's development folder, it can be deduced that it is using Pyfladesk as another library in its facial recognition project and has problems with the installation of that library. Pyfladesk is not a final SW.

Comment: @eyllanesc, ...but this problem isn't meaningfully specific to pyfladesk (or even Python); it's common to *all* software using `libQt5QmlModels` anywhere in its dependency chain.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy python handles its own dependencies (generally), and this is the case. A different question would be: I have installed a final KDE application (which uses that library) and it does not launch the application. In that case you should write to technical support. But not in this case. You may not know much about the world of python and pyqt making you think that it is an OS support problem, IMHO this case is on the edge. I think it already gives my clear position so I won't discuss it anymore, bye.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me

sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine